# How can I customize views for LLDB with Voltron?

Tags: debugging, terminal, customization, lldb

I have ([voltron](https://github.com/snare/voltron)) for LLDB. Windows of registers, a stack, etc. opens separately. How to customize windows so that they settled down all together, how on the picture? I know that it is necessary to use tmuxinator.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to describe each step. First, you need to install voltron, if you have not already done so. Detailed instructions here https://github.com/snare/voltron

Next, install tmux. I used homebrew.

```
brew install tmux
```

In order to get an view, like on the picture, you should customize tmuxinator (more information here https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator).

In the terminal write command

```
echo $EDITOR
export EDITR='vim'
tmuxinator new voltron
```

You should customize the `.yml file`. I used the settings by the voltron author's, but YAML is very particular about how much space is used where (thanks to https://github.com/ethagnawl). To edit voltron.yml i did use the `'i'` button, to save the `Esc` and `'Z'`.

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/voltron.yml
name: voltron
root: ~/
windows:
  # two spaces
  - madhax:
      # four spaces
      layout: 15a8,169x41,0,0{147x41,0,0[147x13,0,0{81x13,0,0,60,65x13,82,0,61},147x19,0,14,62,147x7,0,34{89x7,0,34,63,57x7,90,34,64}],21x41,148,0,65}
      panes:
        # two spaces
        - voltron view disasm
        - voltron view bp
        - lldb
        - voltron view stack
        - voltron view bt
        - voltron view reg
```

To run tmux using:

```
tmuxinator start voltron
```